# Is there any method to verify how many records returned from poll in KStream(Kafka streams) before processing forEach method

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams

I want to know how many records returned from poll in KStream(Kafka streams) before processing forEach method in Kafka Consumer.

Have to create metrics based on how many records returned from poll and can verify how many processed in forEach method.

Can you please have any suggestions for this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count number of records fetched in a poll, you need to use Consumer API, and `.count()` on the `ConsumerRecord` iterator